# Find if some of the element's attributes contains specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was thinking if there is a way to find if element's attribute contains a specified value. The attribute is unknown. If I have this HTML:

```
    <input class="first" type="checkbox" data="THE-VALUE" />
    <input class="second" type="checkbox" />
    <input class="third" type="checkbox" name="THE-VALUE" />
```

I want to find all the inputs that has attribute with value **THE-VALUE** (in this case `.first` and `.third`). I don't need solution for this case where inputs are 3, but if I have 50 inputs and the attributes containing THE-VALUE are all different. I have tried things like `.attr(':contains("THE-VALUE")')` and `$('input[="THE-VALUE"]')`, but by obvious reasons it doesn't work.

So my question is .. is there any way to find that ?

Comment: If you need to do this, you really need to first think about restructuring your application.

Comment: The only way seems to be to iterate over each attribute of each `input` element... it's not pretty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("input").filter(function() {
    return $.grep(this.attributes, function(arg) {
        return arg.nodeValue === "THE-VALUE";
    }).length > 0;
}).prop("checked", true);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7tsZN/

---

Or as a selector extension:

```
$.expr[':'].hasattrval = function(e, i, p) {
    return $.grep(e.attributes, function(arg) {
        return arg.nodeValue === p[3];
    }).length;
};

$("input:hasattrval('THE-VALUE')").prop("checked", true);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7tsZN/1/

Comment: A very nice solution to an awful problem :)

Comment: Very nice even '> 0' check is useless

Comment: @roasted strictly speaking that's true, but it's not obvious when reading the code that the value returned by the `filter` function is evaluated as a boolean. I thin in this case it's better to have the check condition.